# Rails validate uniqueness fails on concurrent inputs

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a `Ticket` model with basic uniqueness validation on a string attribute `ticket_number`

```
validates :ticket_number, uniqueness: true
```

Here is the input code for the `ticket_number`

```
<%= f.number_field :ticket_number, :value => @ticket.ticket_number || (Ticket.exists? ? Ticket.maximum(:ticket_number).next) : 1 , :class => 'form-control' %>
```

The validation seems to work as expected, however when we deployed the app and probably more than one users were entering `tickets` at the same time, which shouldn't cause an issue (right?) we found duplicated records (same ticket number) in the database(MySQL).

It only happened once in a total of 600+ tickets so far but why and how to prevent that from happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very uncommon and you're probably very unlucky that it has, it is possible.

**Read: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb#L165**

Consider the following:
  User A submits form

- User A submits form
- Rails checks database for existing ID for User A- none found
- User B submits form
- Rails checks database for existing ID for User B- none found
- Rails Saves user A record
- Rails saves user B record

All this has to happen within milliseconds but it is technically possible.

I'd suggest adding a constraint at the database level (primary key).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Yule. I've been facing a similar issue but I'm afraid that I cannot put a unique index on the database level. Is there any other option I can try? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

@Yule answer was very helpful , it explained Why this happened and that adding database level constraint will prevent it.

The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html) says, this will throw an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exseption which i don't want the users to see ofcourse, so here is exactly how to apply the workaround suggested by @Yule:

1. **Add an index on the attribute**

   ```
   add_index(:tickets, :ticket_number, :unique => true)
   ```
2. **Adjust the `controller#create` action to catch the db exception**:

```
def create
 @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
 if @ticket.save
   flash[:success] = 'Ticket was successfully created.'
 else
   render action: 'new'
 end
 #catch the exception
 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
   flash[:danger] = 'The ticket number you entered is already taken !'
   render action: 'new'
end
```

*Same should be done for controller#update action ofcourse*

Comment: This is very helpful. But there is a catch. We cannot always add unique database indexes to ensure validations. Sometimes, validations can be conditional. Adding a unique index will make the conditional validation go obsolete. We need some kind of locking mechanism to ensure the validations wait if a different thread is executing some transaction on the same table.