# How do I ensure that duplicate rows are not added to my database table via activerecords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, model

So I have a table called votes.

There are three columns. VoterID, VoteforID and Vote.

The uniqueness of each individual column is not important however, the same row cant repeat twice

For instance. This is correct

Voter_id  |  Votefor_id  |  Vote

1          |         2  |  1

1          |         3  |  1

1          |         4  |  1

2          |        1   |  2

This is wrong.

Voter_id  |  Votefor_id  |  Vote

1          |         2  |  1

1          |         2  |  1

1          |         4  |  1

2          |        1   |  2

Currently, I am doing a select statement before adding records just to make sure that an identical row does not exist. Surely, there is a better solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data integrity is critical, you should not use a validation to guarantee uniqueness. It can fail. The only way to guarantee uniqueness is to use a database constraint. This is because the Rails `validates_uniqueness` can have race conditions.

Create a migration to add the index, or change your existing one to reflect this change:

For a new table:

```
class CreateVotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :votes do |t|
      t.belongs_to :voter
      t.belongs_to :votefor
      t.string :vote # Choose the correct column type
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :votes, [:voter_id, :votefor_id, :vote], unique: true
  end
end
```

For an existing table:

```
class AddUniqueIndexToVotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :votes,  [voter_id, votefor_id, vote], unique: true
  end
end
```

Now you can go ahead and add a validation, as suggested by others, if you want to give your user feedback that they've already voted:

```
validates :voter_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:votefor_id, :vote] }
```

Comment: btw the validation here won't work since DB constraint will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` when uniqueness fails on db side which need to be handled (rescued)

Comment: @Nimir Yes it will. Rails will run the query to verify the uniqueness. It will raise a validation error if it finds matches. The database constraint is just to guarantee that no duplicates will be saved in the event of a race condition that can happen with Rails and it's `uniqueness` validation.

Comment: @Mohamad (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb#L165)

Comment: @Mohamed, you missed out the  ":" before [voter_id, votefor_id, vote]. It should be [:voter_id, :votefor_id, :vote]. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Mohamad I now get the error "PG::Error: ERROR:  could not create unique index '"index_votes_on_voter_id_and_votefor_id_and_vote"
DETAIL:  Key (voter_id, votefor_id, vote)=(581, 51, 2) is duplicated.".' Is there any way I could delete the records automatically which are duplicate. Thank you!

Comment: @Nimir I don't understand what you mean by the link. It says exactly what I said: **IF** there is a race condition, the database will error out. But most of the time, Rails will pick the the validation as normal. That's precisely what I said: The validation will work nearly all of the time.

Comment: @user3649729 can't you just delete them? If this is not production, do `rake db:reset`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `scope` parameter on [uniqueness_validation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of), something like:

```
validates :voter_id, uniqueness: { scope: :votefor_id }
```

scope parameters could be more than one:

```
validates :voter_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:votefor_id, :vote] }
```

#### Update: (App validation Vs Db constraint)

It really depends on the details but for the case in hand my personal opinion that db constraint is a bit overkill here because chances for a race condition ([documented in rails uniqueness validation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb#L165)) to happen are low, since we need

two records with the exact same voter_id, votefor_id and vote to be submitted at the exact same time (we are talking about milliseconds), if i may assume something about the OP business logic that `voter` would normally be a logged in user meaning duplicate entries should only come from him !!

#### conclusion:

I had quite a number of rails apps running in production using `uniqueness_validation` just fine and only [one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814122/rails-validate-uniqueness-fails-on-concurrent-inputs) it failed me in a situation of a uniqueness check on a single column with many simultaneous entries (obviously i needed db constraint there).

If data integrity is critical you should for sure go with db constraint.

Or if you don't mind the overhead & specially if you could benefit from the new index on the (voter_id, votefor_id and vote) to increase search speed i would say go with db constraint.

otherwise i would say: keep it simple and stay with `uniquess_valdation`

Comment: Thanks Nimir, so what is the difference between:
validates :voter_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:votefor_id, :vote] }
and validates :votefor_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:voter_id, :vote] }.thanks again!

Comment: This answer is not correct. It does not guarantee uniqueness. You need a database constraint.

Comment: regarding your inquiry @user3649729 , the params in the `scope` defines what columns should be compared along with `voter_id` for uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

In your table definition, add a `UNIQUE` table constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE votes (
  voter_id   int NOT NULL,
  votefor_id int NOT NULL,
  vote       int NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (voter_id, votefor_id, vote)
);
```

This way PostgreSQL checks for duplicates. If you try to `INSERT` a record whose values are the same for all three columns as in an existing record, then an error will be thrown.

Comment: make that `UNIQUE (voter_id, votefor_id)` Otherwise a person can vote twice (with a different vote value) Also: {voter_id,votefor_id} should be NOT NULLable.

Comment: @wildplasser: Maybe it is valid to cast multiple votes? The OP implies that. Added the `NOT NULL` qualifiers.

Comment: Indeed the OP said that. But to me thi makes no sense: multiple votes are allowed *only* if the have a different value?