# how to delete duplicate row when adding index rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-migrations

So I am trying to add an index on my votes table to prevent duplicate rows from being added.

In my previous stackoverflow question. I asked "How do I ensure that duplicate rows are not added to my database table via activerecords?"
[How do I ensure that duplicate rows are not added to my database table via activerecords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722205/how-do-i-ensure-that-duplicate-rows-are-not-added-to-my-database-table-via-activ/23722263?noredirect=1#comment36462678_23722263)

The answer was adding an index through a database migration and this solved it.

```
class AddUniqueIndexToVotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     add_index :votes,  [:voter_id, :votefor_id, :vote], unique: true
  end
end
```

However, now I get the error.

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  could not create unique index "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_votefor_id_and_vote"
DETAIL:  Key (voter_id, votefor_id, vote)=(581, 519, 2) is duplicated.
```

How do I automatically delete the duplicate rows/row when the migration is run.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can delete duplicate records first with the following sql statement, assuming you have a primary key consisting of one column. Also, be aware that it deletes all duplicate records that do not have the minimum value for their id column.

```
    DELETE FROM votes v WHERE v.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT MIN(id) FROM votes GROUP BY voter_id, votefor_id, vote)
```

Answer (score 0):

run another migration before which will destroy all "duplicates" rows?

you also want to add validates_uniqueness_of to the model

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of